# Android - retrieve value from XML using XPath

Tags: java, android, xpath

I have the following XML retrieved from a web service. How do I get the value of Dependent FirstName i.e( Rajesh)  from the XML, using XPath? This is for the Android. Can anyone help me on this?

```
<Enrollment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ContactInfo>
<_contactRelations/>
<ContactId>83</ContactId>
<ImportId>-1</ImportId>
<ExtContactId>1-CCR1</ExtContactId>
<OrgId>EX-PG-30021045</OrgId>
<ParContactId/>
<EmployeeId>M101</EmployeeId>
<FullName>Mahesh CN</FullName>
<FirstName>Mahesh</FirstName>
<MiddleName/>
<LastName>CN</LastName>
<DOB>1980-03-02T00:00:00</DOB>
<Address1>address</Address1>
<Address2/>
<Address3/>
<City>new city</City>
<County>Saint Lawrence</County>
<State>VA</State>
<PostalCode>11111</PostalCode>
<HomePhoneNo/>
<WorkPhoneNo/>
<CellPhoneNo/>
<EmailAddress>mahesh.narayanan@speridian.com</EmailAddress>
<Active>1</Active>
<InActiveDt>0001-01-01T00:00:00</InActiveDt>
<HiredDt>2012-03-01T00:00:00</HiredDt>
<Designation>SSE</Designation>
<WorkLocation>Chennai</WorkLocation>
<GroupNo>30021045</GroupNo>
<SubGroupNo>A001</SubGroupNo>
<SSN>010101010</SSN>
<Class>Management</Class>
<EULA>1</EULA>
<Gender>M</Gender>
<Type>PGA</Type>
<PartAEffectiveDt>0001-01-01T00:00:00</PartAEffectiveDt>
<PartBEffectiveDt>0001-01-01T00:00:00</PartBEffectiveDt>
<IsDomesticPartner>false</IsDomesticPartner>
<IsFTStudent>false</IsFTStudent>
<GraduationDt>0001-01-01T00:00:00</GraduationDt>
<CreditHours>-1</CreditHours>
<IsDependentHandicapped>false</IsDependentHandicapped>
<TerminationDt>0001-01-01T00:00:00</TerminationDt>
<ReAssignedToCobra>false</ReAssignedToCobra>
<CobraEffectiveDt>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CobraEffectiveDt>
<RecEffectiveDt>2012-01-01T00:00:00</RecEffectiveDt>
<RecTerminationDt>2012-12-31T00:00:00</RecTerminationDt>
<CreatedOn>2012-03-02T14:57:47.687</CreatedOn>
<CreatedBy>SPERIDIAN\sujeeth.anand</CreatedBy>
<ModifiedOn>2012-03-07T10:05:14.28</ModifiedOn>
<ModifiedBy>HR_MSMITH</ModifiedBy>
<UserInfo>
<AccessGroups/>
<UserId>3</UserId>
<ContactId>1-CCR1</ContactId>
<Login>hr_MSmith</Login>
<Password>cGFzc3dvcmQ=</Password>
<LoginAttemptsCnt>0</LoginAttemptsCnt>
<LoginLockedInd>0</LoginLockedInd>
<AllowInternetUse>1</AllowInternetUse>
<Active>-1</Active>
<InActiveDt>0001-01-01T00:00:00</InActiveDt>
<CreatedOn>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreatedOn>
<ModifiedOn>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifiedOn>
<SessionId>B68F7D913FF44B8D9CB7B9F4686D469D</SessionId>
<SessionData>
<ROOT><SESSIONDATA><CLIENT_INFO><USER_ID>3</USER_ID><CONTACT_ID>83</CONTACT_ID><LOGIN_ID>hr_MSmith</LOGIN_ID><ROLE_ID>|7|</ROLE_ID><OBJECT_ACCESS>|01|03|0301|0302|0304|04|0401|0402|0403|0404|0405|0406|08|</OBJECT_ACCESS><FULL_NAME>Mary Smith</FULL_NAME></CLIENT_INFO><PAGE_VARS /><Messaging /></SESSIONDATA></ROOT>
</SessionData>
</UserInfo>
<x001>
<MoreInfo><countryCode>USA</countryCode><phoneExtension /><faxNumber>3152224321</faxNumber><subscriberId /><memberId>M01</memberId><title /></MoreInfo>
</x001>
<ContactRelations/>
</ContactInfo>
<EnrollmentPlans>
<EnrolledPlan>
<PackageId>1-90SBCPDP</PackageId>
<PackageName>SimplyBlue Copay Deduct Plan</PackageName>
<PackageCategory>Medical</PackageCategory>
<CoverageLevel>EMP_SPOUSE</CoverageLevel>
<CoverageLevelDesc>Employee & Spouse</CoverageLevelDesc>
<CoverageAmt>243.33</CoverageAmt>
<TotalCoverageAmt>737.36</TotalCoverageAmt>
<InstallationRowId>28</InstallationRowId>
<EffectiveDate>01/01/2013</EffectiveDate>
<TerminationDate>12/31/2013</TerminationDate>
<IsNew>false</IsNew>
</EnrolledPlan>
</EnrollmentPlans>
<RowId>5</RowId>
<ContactId>1-CCR1</ContactId>
<Type>OPEN_ENROLL</Type>
<OrgId>30021045</OrgId>
<PlanSetupId>28</PlanSetupId>
<EnrollInfoXml>
<EnrollmentInfo><PersonalInfo><EmployeeID>M101</EmployeeID><FirstName>Mahesh</FirstName><MiddleName /><LastName>CN</LastName><DateOfBirth>03/02/1980</DateOfBirth><Gender>M</Gender><SSN>010101010</SSN><Email>mahesh.narayanan@speridian.com</Email><AddressLine1>address</AddressLine1><AddressLine2 /><AddressLine3 /><City>new city</City><State>VA</State><ZipCode>11111</ZipCode><HomePhone /><WorkPhone /></PersonalInfo><WorkInfo><Class>1-CLA1</Class><DateOfHire>03/01/2012</DateOfHire><Designation>SSE</Designation><WorkLocation>Chennai</WorkLocation></WorkInfo><SelectedPackages><Package Id="1-90SBCPDP" Category="Medical" CoverageLevel="EMP_SPOUSE" CoverageAmt="243.33" TotalCoverageAmt="737.36" InstallationRowId="28" EffectiveDate="01/01/2013" TerminationDate="12/31/2013"><Dependents><Dependent ExtContactId="REF-445"><FirstName>Rajesh</FirstName><MiddleName>R</MiddleName><LastName>Rai</LastName><DateOfBirth>01/03/1980</DateOfBirth><Gender>M</Gender><Relationship>DEP</Relationship><AddressLine1>address</AddressLine1><AddressLine2 /><AddressLine3 /><City>new city</City><State>VA</State><ZipCode>11111</ZipCode><HomePhone>4254545</HomePhone><MedicareNumber /><PartA_EffectiveDate /><PartB_EffectiveDate /><IsFullTimeStudent>False</IsFullTimeStudent><CollegeName /><ExpectedGraduationDate /><CreditHours /></Dependent></Dependents></Package></SelectedPackages></EnrollmentInfo>
</EnrollInfoXml>
<EffectiveDt>2013-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveDt>
<TerminationDt>2013-12-31T00:00:00</TerminationDt>
<Status>CO</Status>
<Active>1</Active>
<TaskId>-1</TaskId>
<CreatedOn>2012-03-12T11:09:09.21</CreatedOn>
<CreatedBy>WSWIN7001\BRYMY DWCC6 G8YPG</CreatedBy>
<ModifiedOn>2012-03-13T15:00:07.95</ModifiedOn>
<ModifiedBy>hr_MSmith</ModifiedBy>
<StatusDesc>Completed (Waiting for approval)</StatusDesc>
<TotalPlanAmount>0</TotalPlanAmount>
<TotalEmployeeContribution>0</TotalEmployeeContribution>
</Enrollment>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not mention which version of Android you are targeting, but on current versions of Android, the following code will get you the first name from the XML. You have to set the xml variable to the XML you got from the web service and you will find the result in the firstName variable.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

...

  String xml = "<...>";
  String expression = "/Enrollment/FirstName";

  DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  Document document = builder.parse(in);

  XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
  Node firstNameNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
  String firstName = firstNameNode.getTextContent();
```